# Separate files by name into different folders

Tags: macos, mac, bash, terminal, file-management

If I have a folder containing various files with the same pattern, for example:

```
 file1a
 file1b
 file1c
 file2a
 file2b
 file2c
 ...
```

Is there a one-liner for separating them into folders named:

```
file1/file1a, file1b, file1c
file2/file2a, file2b, file2c
```

What's variable: number of those folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `for` loop:

```
for f in file*; do 
  mkdir -p "${f%%[^0-9]}"
  mv -v "$f" "${f%%[^0-9]}/"
done
```

---

- It loops trough all files in the directory starting with `file`.
- `mkdir -p` creates the directory if it doesn't exist.

  - `${f%%[^0-9]}`: this removes the part which not `^` contains numbers from the back of the filename; that's the directory name.
- And finally `mv` move the file in the corresponding directory.

---

The directory tree after execution:

```
├── file1
│   ├── file1a
│   ├── file1b
│   └── file1c
└── file2
    ├── file2a
    ├── file2b
    └── file2c
```

Comment: One more thing: instead of removing the part which doesn't contain numbers, is there a general way to remove anything AFTER the number? (The next digit after the number will not be a number, but after that it could be anything)

Comment: @lhcgeneva Try it with `sed 's/\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/' <<<"$f"`. This removes everything after the first number.

Comment: Ok, I've tried various things now, can't get it to work. Stupid question, where do I put the above comment? :D I would have thought something like  `mkdir -p "${sed 's/\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/' <<<"$f"}/"` but that gives me _bad expansion_

Comment: @lhcgeneva Sorry, if it was unclear. I meant: `mkdir -p $(sed 's/\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/' <<<"$f")` and `mv -v "$f" "$(sed 's/\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/' <<<"$f")"`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work me, but I think I've found a way around it using  indexing, so no worries and thanks!