# Moving files into separate folders

Tags: powershell, cmd.exe

I have a folder in which I create multiple screenshots per day '`[projectname].[date].[time].png`'

So it looks like this:

```
ProjectAlpha.2020-11-10.09-53-21.png
ProjectAlpha.2021-05-20.15-10-43.png
ProjectBeta.2020-11-10.09-53-28.png
ProjectBeta.2021-05-20.15-11-24.png
ProjectBeta.2021-07-27.11-34-42.png
ProjectDelta.2021-05-20.15-19-01.png
ProjectDelta.2021-05-20.15-09-42.png
ProjectDelta.2021-07-27.11-35-03.png
```

I want the part before the first 'dot' to be the foldername and then move all into their corresponding folder.

So the result will look like this:

```
├── ProjectAlpha
│   ├── ProjectAlpha.2020-11-10.09-53-21.png
│   └── ProjectAlpha.2021-05-20.15-10-43.png
└── ProjectBeta
│   ├── ProjectBeta.2020-11-10.09-53-28.png
│   ├── ProjectBeta.2021-05-20.15-11-24.png
│   └── ProjectBeta.2021-07-27.11-34-42.png
└── ProjectDelta
    ├── ProjectDelta.2021-05-20.15-19-01.png
    └── ProjectDelta.2021-05-20.15-09-42.png
```

I found something similar in [this Powershell](https://superuser.com/questions/1473814/moving-folders-based-on-condition) post and [this CMD](https://superuser.com/questions/1005253/separate-files-by-name-into-different-folders) post, but I can't get it to work for my situation.

Is there anyone who can help me with this please?

Comment: Although this is definitely possible to script, I'm pretty sure you can optimize this further by just making sure the folder is selected automatically when you make the screenshot. For example, this is easily setup in Greenshot but other tools also have this feature, so it depends on what tool you use, it is more practical to eliminate it at the source and just move the remaining files once (which can be scripted of course)

Comment: Hi @LPChip, in hindsight this is great. But I got years and dozens of small projects to sort.

Comment: Just mentioning that you may want to consider running the script on a regular basis if you can save them to the right spot in the first place. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, paste this code in notepad and save with the name that you want but with a *.bat extension. Next drag and drop the folder where the projects are (images) to the batch file...

```
@echo off

:: Please drag and drop the folder where the projects are to this batch script

if exist "%~1" (if not exist "%~1\" exit) else (exit)

set "Folder=%~1"
Set Files=*.jpg *.png *.gif *.webp

pushd "%Folder%"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /on %Files%') do for /f "delims=." %%b in ("%%~a") do (
                                                                                             if not exist "%%b" md "%%b"
                                                                                             move "%%a" "%%b"
                                                                                            )
exit
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

With Powershell, try the following:

```PS
$mypath = Get-Location
$files = Get-ChildItem

$files | Where { $_ -match "project[a-z]+"} | 
ForEach { 
            if ( !( Test-Path -Path $Matches[0] )) { 
                    New-Item -Path   $Matches[0] -ItemType Directory 
                }

            $files = $Matches[0] + "*.*"
            Move-Item -Path $files -Destination $Matches[0] 
    }
```

Comment: The project names were just an example, the actual names are random with a random length, and this part 'match "project[a-z]' is exactly why the linked examples didn't work for me.
But [Ricardo's](https://superuser.com/a/1728359/267461) script works for me as intended.
Thank you for your effort.